# Importing Data in salesforce from external system using .csv file with FTP server

Tags: apex, integration, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job, ftp

Here i have the requirement to use FTP server in salesforce..

-- we have one external system and data inserted into it day by day

-- after that at the end of the day one file(.csv) automatically generated to that external system

**-- How can i access of that file(.csv) from external system in salesforce using FTP server**

**-- after having that file's data i need to insert that data automatically(scheduled) in salesforce which is coming from external system**

How can i achieve this ?

Please suggest the way..

thanks

Comment: Question is still not clear. You can not directly get file from FTP -- you need to have proxy (https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000093ZAIAY). If you got file -- then you can parse that in apex and perform dml based on that. You can have scheduled job to do that

Comment: edited the question..hope it is clear now...

Comment: 1) You need proxy to access that file from salesforce by HttpRequest. 2) You can create scheduled job to check if there are unprocessed files by request, download that file, parse via apex and perform dml based on file content. Those are suggestions how would I do that.

Comment: Ok...let me try to get the proxy of that file and will do proceed...thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Dataloader CLI to automate the process of importing the records into salesforce from csv file. Since you are using a FTP server , you can schedule a windows batch job that can pick the .csv file placed at a location in the server and you can call dataloader from the same bat file. You can schedule the bat file in task scheduler to run at whatever time you want.

These links can help you setup the dataloader CLI:

> https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=using_the_command_line_interface.htm&type=0&language=en_US
>
> http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/tutorial-of-command-line-dataloader-salesforce/

Hope this is helpful!